# React-Native render a Card Component using FlatList not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

I'm new to React-Native I want to render the Card Component with different json data from an external file. My problem which i don't see is that the card component image is not showing and the card components are not stacking on top of each other. This is what i have so far. The card Component is being rendered through it's parent component which is Recipie.

Below is the Parent Component Recipie

```
import RecipieData from '../Data/Data'

const Recipies = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.background}>
            <View style={styles.cards}>
                <FlatList
                    style={{height: '100%'},{width:"100%"}}
                    data={RecipieData}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => 
                        
                        <Card
                            image={item.photo}
                            title={item.name}
                            time={item.time}
                        />
                        }
                />
            </View>
            
            
        </View>
    )
}

export default Recipies

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background:{
        backgroundColor:'#F2F2F2',
        height: "100%",
        flex: 1,
    },
    cards:{
        marginHorizontal:20,
        marginVertical:30,
        
    }
})
`
```

Here is the Child Component Card

```
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <LikeButton/>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: props.image}}/>
            
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.time}>{props.time}</Text>
        </View>
            
        
    )
}

export default Card

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    card:{
        marginVertical:15,
        width:'100%',
        borderRadius:35,
        backgroundColor:'black',

    },
    image:{
        marginLeft:0,
        padding:0,
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        borderRadius:30,
        position:'relative',
        opacity:0.65
    },
    title:{
        position:'absolute',
        marginTop:65,
        marginBottom:0,
        marginHorizontal:20,
        fontSize: 30,
        color:'white',
        fontWeight:'bold'

    }, time:{
        width:'20%',
        textAlign:'center',
        marginVertical: 20,
        position:'absolute',
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        color:'white',
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        bottom:0,
        borderRadius:20,
        marginLeft: 20
    }
})
```

I've tried everything . I'm really trying to get the card components stacked in a column view with the props from the external json file called RecipieData. Please can someone help me it will be much appreciated!!!!

Comment: Hi there, looks like it may be an issue with flexbox. If you want them to be in a row, and then wrap, you could specify that in your Recipe component. Also, you could play around with the horizontal/column settings: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `cards:{ marginHorizontal:20, marginVertical:30, flex : 1 }`

Comment: you didn't give flex to cards in styles on Recipies (sorry my eng is bad, i hope i can help you)

Comment: Welcome. If you have additional info to add to your own post, it is better to edit, than to add it to the comments section. If you realize this wasn't a proper Answer to this again, you can delete the post instead. Also, know that code-only answers are discouraged on SO, are less likely to be upvoted, as their long term value, and opportunities to learn from raw code with no context or explanation limit learning opportunities for future visitors to easily learn from and apply the knowledge to their own code.

Answer (score 0):

renderItem should return a component.Use this

```
renderItem={({ item }) => 
             return(<Card
                        image={item.photo}
                        title={item.name}
                        time={item.time}
                    />)}
```